# meteor social login work only on localhost

Tags: android, facebook, meteor, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have tried implementing Facebook and Twitter login in meteor android app using [this](http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/login-with-facebook-twitter-and-google-in-meteor) tutorial. Everything works fine on localhost. Now I changed it to work on real domain but it didn't work. I use mup to deploy the app on AWS. I tried all combinations of ROOT_URL but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Removing port number from the connection urls from all the places solved it.